# store key in a variable for each ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am fairly new to angular js.
I have two different scope data in my controller ($scope.itemdata & $scope.skudata, both are simplified in the plucker). Both are guaranteed to have the same structure for any key.
I have a nested ng-repeat for item data and I want to store/keep a track of keys inside each ng-repeat so that I can use the path variable to get the value out of skudata. 
Problem:  {{path}} expression in HTML is not resolving to correct key value. 
Looking at the console log the keys are added and removed in the correct order. 
I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Here is plucker : http://plnkr.co/edit/0q8tZ9JLsGdfR03YbpYB?p=info

```
HTML Code:<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello</p>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="field_renderer.html">

<div ng-init="addkeyToPath(key)"></div>
  {{key}} 
  {{value}}
  <!--output should be skudata.value but instead its skudata-->
  {{path}}

<div ng-init="removeKeyFromPath(key)"></div> 
 {{path}}


</script>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="(key ,value) in itemData" ng-include="'field_renderer.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.path = 'skudata';

  $scope.isThisAnObject = function(input) {
    return angular.isObject(input) ? true : false;
  }
  $scope.addkeyToPath = function(input) {
    console.log("Adding");
    console.log($scope.path);
    $scope.path =  $scope.path + "." + input;
    console.log($scope.path);
   };

   $scope.removeKeyFromPath = function(input) {
     console.log("remove");
    console.log($scope.path);
    $scope.path = $scope.path.substring(0,$scope.path.lastIndexOf("."));
    console.log($scope.path);
   };

  $scope.itemData =
  { value:'item_name', 
    length:'10'

  };

  $scope.skudata =
  { value:'sku_name', 
    length:'20'

  };


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the `$scope` path variable, when really you want to display path variable of the item itself. Make a few changes to get [this working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RgaqkRZWWUFAnRmHJzNc?p=preview)

Template:

```
<div ng-init="addkeyToPath(this, key)">
  {{key}}: {{value}}
  {{path}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addkeyToPath = function(item, input) {
  item.path = $scope.path + "." + input;
 };

$scope.itemData = { 
  value:'item_name', 
  length:'10'
};
```

Comment: thanks azium, but I don't want to display the path variable. Rather my intend was to use the path variable to get the value from "skuData" present in my plunker. So basically I am iterating through itemData and wanted to store the keys that I have iterated through ( path = k1.k2.k3..) and use the path to get the value present at that parth in "skuData"..Does that make it clear.

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just directly get `skuData` then? Why do you need to use `path` at all?

Comment: Problem : When you find a value for a key in "item data" ..look if a value exists for that key in "sku data" ..if yes..then fetch the value from the skudata. Please note that itemdata and skudata can be nested objects.